# Why can't I access a remote database through Java?

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

I am trying to make an Java application, which needs a connection with a MySQL database to read data.

I've read several tutorials and examples, and I tried almost everything but I just can't get any access to the database.

At the moment I am using this to connect to the db:

```
try{
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://myhost/test","databaseUser",  "password");
}
catch (Exception e){
   System.out.println(e);
}
```

Stacktrace:

> com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:

> ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

> com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException
> MESSAGE: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:

> ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

> java.io.EOFException
> MESSAGE: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.

> STACKTRACE:

> java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
> at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1997)
> at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:573)
> at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1044)
> at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2775)
> at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.(Connection.java:1555)
> at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
> at facturatiesysteem.SysteemView.zoekKlant(SysteemView.java:148)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
> at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.noProxyActionPerformed(ApplicationAction.java:662)
> at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.actionPerformed(ApplicationAction.java:698)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
> at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6288)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
> at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6053)
> at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4651)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
> at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:643)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
> at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:616)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:614)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:613)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)

> ** END NESTED EXCEPTION **

The last packet sent to the server was 16 ms ago.

And a lot more...

But I just can't get access to it.

What can I do here?

Comment: Please show us your stack trace (the exception)!!!

Comment: Yes, assuming you get an exception, do `e.printStackTrace()` instead, and show us the output.

Comment: BTW: I'd not post the database details in a public forum...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

phpmyadmin is a front-end to a database, a web application. It's not a database. You can't access the database in Java through phpmyadmin. You need a direct access to the database itself (which is called MySQL, BTW). Not sure if your hosting provider allows it.

Comment: Thanks for your information. So I guess there isn't a way to acces the data stored in the database?

Comment: Ask your hosting provider. It might be possible, but I doubt it. If you don't need access to live data, you might export the data through phpmyadmin, import it in a local database on your machine, and access this local database from Java.